# How does a compiled vue.js or angular component work? Can you use it like a normal, plain HTML project?

Tags: angular, vue.js

The title might be a bit confusing. I think i'm missing some basic understanding of how a framework like vue.js or even angular works once compiled.

Can i technically, just take the compiled html/css/js, and run it standalone?

As an example:

If i create a component, lets say its a navigation component. Could i just compile it, and then copy paste the compiled HTML to another, possibly vanilla js project?
Will the whole data-binding, change detection etc. work?

Thanks

Comment: Basically the answer is just yes, it all ends up in HTML, CSS and JS files that can be served by any standard web server.

Comment: As long as you copy all the generated files over it should work. Notice you likely have something like `id="app"` where the vue instance is put in. If you add several vue apps in one page the id has to be different.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "compiled". There's build step that could be called compilation, and there's template compilation that could be called compilation. The result of build step is standalone html+css+js code. "Will the whole data-binding, change detection etc. work?" - how could it possibly work? HTML is static. This would be no different from rendering HTML in any other way, e.g. PHP.

Comment: @EstusFlask
I'm pretty bad at formulating questions. By compilation i mean the build process, probably done by npm build or similar.

I have to create a very dynamic component, that makes api calls every minute or so, and changes the rendered data accordingly. For this i would use the integrated change-detection.
The question at hand is, whether i can code this independently from the project it will be used in, and then just copy-paste the compiled/build HTML-CSS-JS.

Comment: Yes, you can, that's the point of build step. What you get in `dist` folder is what you could call vanilla JS. There are regular JS files that contain all framework code. If you need it to be a widget on existing page rather than SPA then you need to include assets on that page instead of using compiled index.htm.

Comment: @EstusFlask
Thanks, that puts my mind at ease.
Could you elaborate on the widget part? The plan is to have multiple components, that then get added (i guess they could be called widgets) inside another project.
So i don't need the whole index.html, as there won't really be an app, but only components. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: The result of build process is called an app. The problem with default build is that it's expected that there's 1 app instance per page by default. You can modify root selector and initialization process as you need to handle multiple app instances. But for your case web components may be more suitable. Check how WC are built in the framework you're interested.

Comment: @EstusFlask After reading this page: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/web-components.html
It sounds very similar (or exactly) like what i need. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I think i have enough information to have a rough idea of how i can solve this.
If you want, you can create an answer in this thread, which i will mark as solution.
Thanks a bunch for your help. This really put my mind at ease (knowing i wasn't completely wrong with my assumptions).